# caffe create_list.sh throws exception in get_image_size.cpp

Tags: caffe

I have been following https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd to get the caffe environment working.  I have gotten upto step 3.

The following line of script is throwing exception.. What could be wrong? 
./data/VOC0712/create_list.sh

```
I0101 21:34:28.608160  2648 get_image_size.cpp:105] Processed 4952 files.
*** Error in `/home/ram/project/caffe/data/VOC0712/../../build/tools/get_image_size': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000025602c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fc8422137e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7fc84221c37a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fc84222053c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9(_ZN6google8protobuf8internal28DestroyDefaultRepeatedFieldsEv+0x1f)[0x7fc841ecc8af]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9(_ZN6google8protobuf23ShutdownProtobufLibraryEv+0x8b)[0x7fc841ecbb3b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3(+0x233b9)[0x7fc82670e3b9]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x10de7)[0x7fc843a9cde7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x39ff8)[0x7fc8421d5ff8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3a045)[0x7fc8421d6045]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0x7fc8421bc837]
/home/ram/project/caffe/data/VOC0712/../../build/tools/get_image_size[0x4039d9]
```

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this issue by running under python3 instead of python2.

alias python=python3